# Why does SSMS allow login when SQL Server is set to Force Encrption, and 'encrypt connection' option is not selected in the SSMS login options

Tags: sql-server, security, encryption

These are the steps I followed to encrypt sql server and client connection :

1. sql server configuration manager -> right click on the MSSQLServer instance -> click properties -> set force encryption to Yes, -> add the certificate -> apply -> ok .
2. sql server configuration manager -> right click on the network configuration -> click properties -> set encryption to Yes, -> trust server certificate to no -> apply -> ok .
3. RESTART SQL Service.

Problem:

1. When I run SSMS on the same machine and try to login without checking the box encrypt connection, SQL Server allows me to login, but
2. When I run SSMS on a different machine and try to login without checking the box encrypt connection, SQL Server fails login

So, why is there a difference in behavior in localhost and remote connection?

Answer (score 1):

The reason it works from local host is that, it is the trusted server since the certificate has been uploaded on that server and has nothing to protect against, whereas if you're coming from another server, that's where the Trust server is not applicable since it doesn't have the certificate that's required to authenticate and in which case it serves the purpose of this authentication.

For more details on this subject checkout: [Enable Encrypted Connections to the Database Engine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-encrypted-connections-to-the-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

The Certificates and encryption settings are for the TCP/IP protocol only.

On the same computer it will connect with Shared Memory or Names Piped.